# How to send a large payload via SSH without hijacking stdin?

Tags: ssh

I want to run an `ssh` command that carries some large data (e.g. a binary file) to the remote server (i.e. I can't put that data as a command-line argument), but I don't want to redirect the user's stdin.

I can obviously do this with 2 ssh commands (or via `scp` etc.), but what is the proper way to do this in one single SSH command?

I know I can port-forward and try to send data that way, but it seems a bit dirty of an approach, and I'm concerned that might make the port available to too many programs on the remote host.

Is there a cleaner/better way?

Comment: Can you explain why simply using `scp` isn't a viable option? Because that seems simpler than anything else you're discussing.

Comment: I don't see much of a use case either. If you just want to re-use an SSH connection, use control files (see `ControlMaster`, `ControlPersist` in `man ssh_config`)

Comment: Also consider the likelihood of the SSH connection breaking in the middle of transferring a large payload. `scp` (or `ssh`) cannot resume a transfer, so you'd have to restart it from the beginning.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa: That's actually fine. The payload isn't *that* large, it's just too large to be an argument.

Comment: @larsks: For one thing I don't want to write it to disk on either side if I can help it.

Comment: @muru: Well, if nothing else, `ControlMaster` et al. don't seem to work with my SSH on Windows, so I can't use them even if I want to (which I don't). But for the sake of this question, I want to understand if there's even a proper way to do this, not have an argument about whether or not it's warranted in my particular case.

Comment: What SSH is that? If you don't specify what you're using, whether an answer is possible or not simply can't be determined a

Comment: @muru: MSYS2's, but again, I'm not interested in trying to get a multiplexing solution working... I already know how to do that regardless... I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to do it instead. If the answer is "no, there's no better way", then that's fine, please just post that as an answer.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you mean by "redirecting the user's standard input", i.e. an example of an `ssh` command that you _don't_ want to use, preferably with an explanation of why.

Comment: @Kusalananda: it's been 3 years, so I forget the exact use case, but one place this would still come up for me is when say you're making an SSH wrapper that copies some files to the remote machine before an interactive session starts. As just one example.